# Does a static member inside a nested class have static duration for the enclosing class?

Tags: c++, inner-classes, static-members

If I have nested classes, and these nested classes have static members, will those members still be static for the enclosing class? For example, if I have

```
class Enclosing {
public:
    Enclosing();
private:
    class Nested {
    public:
        Nested();
    private:
        static int thing;
    };
};
```

If I do

```
auto A = Enclosing();
auto B = Enclosing();
```

Will `A` and `B` be able to have different values for `thing`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will `A` and `B` be able to have different values for `thing`?

No they won't have different values. All instances will see the same value for `thing`; the nesting of the class has no impact here.

`static` member variables are "associated with the class" (i.e. over non-static members that are associated with the instances of the class). [From cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Static_data_members);

> Static data members are not associated with any object. They exist even if no objects of the class have been defined. If the static member is declared `thread_local` (since C++11), there is one such object per thread. Otherwise, there is only one instance of the static data member in the entire program, with static storage duration.

[Live sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbde6e9d0533fe82).